# Fit distribution to empirical data

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

I am trying to fit a beta distribution to a histogram created from empirical data.

The problem I encounter is that the fitted distribution is much higher than the bars in the original histogram.

The original data is outside the range of [0,1] which is the range in which the beta distribution can be evaluated so I rescale the original data so that it lies in the interval [0,1].

Here's my code:

```
 load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3psxx8jjbc20mo/data.Rdata?dl=0")

  #create histogram with values normalized between 0 and 1
  h <- hist((data-min(data)) / (max(data)-min(data)),lty="blank",col="grey")
  #normalize the density so the y-axis goes from 0 to 1
  h$density <- h$counts/max(h$counts)
  #plot the results
  plot(h,freq=FALSE,cex.main=1,cex.axis=1,yaxt='n',ylim=c(0,1.5),col='grey',lty='blank',xaxt='n')
  axis(2,at=seq(0,1,0.5),labels=seq(0,1,0.5))
  axis(1,at=seq(0,1,0.5),labels=seq(0,1,0.5))

  #fit beta distribution
  a <- (data-min(data)) / (max(data)-min(data))
  a[a==1] <- 0.9999
  a[a==0] <- 0.0001
  fit.beta <- suppressWarnings(fitdistr(a, "beta", start = list( shape1=0.1, shape2=0.1 ) ))

  #overlay curve from beta distribution
  alpha <- fit.beta$estimate[1]
  beta <- fit.beta$estimate[2]
  b <- rbeta(length(data),alpha,beta)
  lines(density(b))
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: "normalize the density so the y-axis goes from 0 to 1" Why do you do that? Density values are not limited to the interval [0, 1].

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375961/my-density-plot-in-r-has-values-beyond-1-how-can-i-fix-this/37378212#37378212 for a post related to Roland's comment. There is a distinction between the support (`x` values) and the range (`y` values). The support of the beta distribution is on the 0-1 interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will want to use `hist(..., freq=TRUE)` for the histogram. Then, to correctly set the y-axis range, you can compute the maximum value of your beta distribution ([see e.g. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)). Finally, it woul be much better to use `dbeta` than generate a random sample followed by estimating the density:

```
maxibeta <- dbeta((alpha-1)/(alpha+beta-2), alpha, beta)
hist( (data-min(data)) / (max(data)-min(data)), 
      prob=TRUE, col="grey", border="white", ylim=c(0, maxibeta), 
      main="Histogram + fitted distribution")
plot(function(x) dbeta(x,alpha,beta), add=TRUE, col=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

EDIT: a more general solution, but which makes me a little sad because it does not use the nice properties of the beta distribution:

```
fbeta <- function(x)  dbeta(x,alpha,beta)
maxibeta <- optimize(fbeta, interval = c(0,1), maximum = TRUE)$objective

histo <- hist((data-min(data)) / (max(data)-min(data)), plot = FALSE)

plot(histo, freq=FALSE, col="grey", border="white", 
     ylim=c(0, max(maxibeta, max(histo$density))), 
     main="Histogram + fitted distribution")
plot(fbeta, add=TRUE, col=2, lwd=2)
```

Comment: this works in general, but not for all data. For example if you try it with this data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ola5hj2sikigtzs/data2.Rdata?dl=0 the plot looks quite weird. is there a way to make it more flexible?

Comment: The formula I used to compute the maximum value of the theoretical distribution is only good when both shape parameters are > 1. This is not the case for your *data2* example.

Comment: Or implement the different cases listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: Yes, in (almost) exactly the same way you rescaled you initial sample. The real question is: why would you like to do this?

Comment: I recommend against doing it: working with densities makes sense to me, scaling everything to have what you call *probabilities* makes less sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just accepted the question. Just for the sake of completeness could you explain how one could convert the densities to probabilities?